# Getting SL to recognize Swift Object as Image... SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group/createFromExternalSource.json

Tags: swift, image, import

SoftLayer support sent me to stackoverflow because they could not figure this out.

I have uploaded a VHD file to Swift object storage to import it as an Image. Because the image is larger than 2GB, I have uploaded all 2GB chunks and have created the appropriate manifest object in Swift to let me download the joined chunks. After uploading to Swift I can download the manifest URL and the MD5 for the uploaded file and the downloaded file match and I can boot the disk image locally. I do not have a Swift problem.

However, I can not get the SL portal or the API to consistently recognize my Swfit manifest object URI as a valid image. It works sometimes, but not others. I have tried making the Content-Type on the manifest object 'application/binary','application/octet-stream', and 'application/iso-9660-image' without success.

Typically I get a 500 error back from the:

SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group/createFromExternalSource.json

call with the error body: {"error":"The supplied file must be a image.","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Public"}

Can anyone tell me definitively what the Content-Type should be (BTW curl uploads the chunks as 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' and the manifest file as 'application/octet-stream') to make both the SL portal and the API work consistently?

Comment: I have the feeling this question is not about Apple's programming language, Swift, am I correct?

Comment: IBM Swift = Soft Layer OpenStack Swift based object storage

Comment: It appears that the image createFromExternalSource behaves differently based on the file extension of the stored file object. This is not documented anywhere.

Can someone on the Soft Layer API team tell me what specific extension / Content-Type combinations are being checked? It appears that ".vhd" seems to work.